# Header Directories in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directory

Let's say I have a solution/project called myTest, which just has a `myTest.cpp` file.  In some completely separate folder (a Subversion folder on my desktop, for example), I have a `myTest.h` file.

In Xcode, I can drag `myTest.h` into the "Groups and Files" pane and I will be able to use `myTest.h` by putting `#include "myTest.h` in `myTest.cpp`.

Is there any similar functionality for Visual Studio 2010?  Dragging the file into the "Solution Explorer" pane does not work.  I can set the "Include Directories" property, but then I have to use `#include <myTest.h>` rather than `#include "myTest.h"`.  This will cause portability problems later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add additional include directories in the C/C++ page of your project-properties.
then you can use `#include "..."`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `""` and `<>` is that files included with `""` will be found in the same directory as the source file, *or* in the system include path. Files included with `<>` are found *only* in the system include path.

Given that, do you have a file in your source directory that is the same name as the file you're trying to include?

Comment: I do not.  I was working on this same project in Xcode (on another computer, obviously)  and adding the header file via "Add Existing Files" let me use `""`, so I figured there must also be a way of doing this in VS.